# C++ handleProcess Error

Tags: c++

I've been trying to code a C++ memory editor, and although I included the `#include <Windows.h>` library it still gives my an error the " handleprocess Was Not Declared!". Here is the code:

```
#include iostream
#include Windows.h

using namespace std;

int newScore;

int main()
{

HWND windowProgram = FindWindow(NULL,"Calculator");

cout << "Enter A new value to write:";
cin>>::newScore;

if(windowProgram == 0) {
    cerr << "Unable To Locate Window" <<endl;
}else {
    DWORD processID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowProgram,&processID);
    HANDLE handleProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,processID);
}
    if(!handleProcess){
        cerr << "Unable to handle process: " <<handleProcess<< " ! " << endl;
    }else {
        int memoryHack = WriteProcessMemory(
        handleProcess,
        (LPVOID)0XA18803B1CC,
        &newScore,
        (DWORD)sizeof(newScore),NULL);
        if(memoryHack > 0){
            clog<< " Memory Written" <<endl;
        }else{
            cerr<<"Failed to write to memory"<<endl;
        }
        CloseHandle(handleProcess);
    }
    cin.sync(),
    cin.ignore();

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: C++ has scopes so what you declare doesn't pollute everything else. Trying to access a variable from a different scope is like trying to access one function's parameter from another function. That would create a giant mess.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `handleProcess` somewhere else so that it's visible outside the `else` scope. For example:

```
// ...

HANDLE handleProcess = 0; // Declare and initialize here.

if (windowProgram == 0) {
    cerr << "Unable To Locate Window" <<endl;
} else {
    DWORD processID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowProgram, &processID);
    handleProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
}
if (!handleProcess) {
// ...
```

Note that this isn't just an identifier visibility problem. When the scope is exited, non-static variables created on the stack and inside the scope are destroyed and don't exist anymore.